# Can't read JSON value inside a JsonArray from a REST GET request

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have a response from a `GET` call to a REST API that looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "id": "ac:de:23:11:32:40",
    "type": "uwb",
    "name": "Employee tag 12",
    "sensors": "string",
    "fence_timeout": 5,
    "exit_tolerance": 0,
    "tolerance_timeout": 0,
    "exit_delay": 100,
    "properties": {}
  }
]
```

I want just the name "Test".

For testing reasons I wrote the following small program. But unfortunately I can't access "Name".

Can someone give me the last tip to make this work? Or are there better ways to access json values?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Security;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(myJsonResponse);
        //string name = obj. ??????????????????
    }
}

public class MyArray
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("MyArray")]
    public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Think about what you're trying to deserialize to - a `List<Root>`, where each `Root` would *itself* contain a list. Do you see a nested list in your JSON? Nope, there's just an outer one. In other words, your JSON represents a `List<MyArray>` rather than a `List<Root>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a root property, it is just an array. So use this code

```
List<MyArray> listMyArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(myJsonResponse);

string name = listMyArray[0].Name;
```

Answer (score -1):

If the list always contain 1 element you can easily achive this with:

You are deserializing the json object to the wrong class, you should use **`List<MyArray>`**

## Linq

This will use Linq to get the first element of the list, or it defaults value.

```cs
var obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(myJsonResponse);
var name  = obj.FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
```

## Using Array Index

This will use Linq to get the first element of the list, or it defaults value.

```cs
var obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(myJsonResponse);
var name  = obj.[0]?.Name;
```

Case you want to select all names from the array you could use:

```cs
var obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(myJsonResponse);
var names = list.Select(c => c.Name)?.ToList() ?? new List<string>();
```

Comment: This is really not the problem.

Comment: //string name = obj. ??????????????????  Looks like that's what he wants.

Comment: You've *massively* changed the answer since I commented. Although really, the only important part is "You are deserializing the json object to the wrong class" - which is better explained in Serge's answer.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the answer to make it more clear since you said that it doesn't answered the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
As per tripletex API 2.0 documentation 
your object should be 

> Blockquote

{"yourProperty":[{{
    "id": "ac:de:23:11:32:40",
    "type": "uwb",
    "name": "Employee tag 12",
    "sensors": "string",
    "fence_timeout": 5,
    "exit_tolerance": 0,
    "tolerance_timeout": 0,
    "exit_delay": 100,
    "properties": {}
  }}]}

> Blockquote
```

> Blockquote
> var data = yourPayload.Children().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Path.Equals("yourProperty", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
> var list = data ?.First.ToObject<List>();

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, but it's not helpful IMO... the JSON is being returned from a REST API; the OP presumably can't change that. They *can* change the code used to parse it.